# How to connect two projects work with each other at same database in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm making two Apps so if I do add, update or delete in App1 it should reflect in App2 and what are the things do to connect both apps work with each other with same database in Firebase ?

Answer (score 1):

Add both the android project to same firebase project, add fingerprints in firebase,  give address of same database node in both the android project and you are good to go.
Firebase supports multiple project linking.